# Render using formatted data, Sort using raw data in DataTables.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Here is a sample of my datatables config

```
{
    "dom"        : "rltip",
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : false,
    "order"      : [ [ 1 , "desc" ] ],
    "searching"  : false,
    data: [
       { "column-a" : "Sample Data A" , "column-b" : 10 , "column-c" : "Blah Blah" },
       { "column-a" : "Sample Data B" , "column-b" : 5 , "column-c" : "Blah Blah" },
       { "column-a" : "Sample Data C" , "column-b" : 38 , "column-c" : "Blah Blah" }
    ],
    "columnDefs" : [
        {
            "targets"   : 0,
            "orderable" : false,
            "data"      : "column-a"
        },
        {
            "targets"   : 1,
            "orderable" : false,
            "data"      : "column-b"
        },
        {
            "targets"   : 2,
            "orderable" : true,
            "className" : "title",
            "data"      : "column-c"
        }
     ]
}
```

I wanted to format the data on display, but on sorting and other backend related stuff, i want to use the raw unformated data.

**Important: I must do this on client side ( javascript ).**

I already tried the **render** function callback on the **columnDefs** but it doesn't seem to work.

```
"render" : function( data , type , row ) {

    if ( type === "sort" )
        return data;

    // format data here
    return data; // This is a formatted data

}
```

What i mean about "it doesn't seem to work" is the sorting is broken, it will take in consideration the formatted data, not just the raw data.

I found this old related article but it doesnt seem to be applicable anymore to the newer version of datatables.net

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8249/filtering-using-the-rendered-text-however-sorting-using-the-original-value

I am using version **1.10.15**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [render function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) is called multiple times with different values in *type*. If you set the unformatted data only to the type **sort**, you miss other for the sorting relevant types like **type**. Instead handle the case of *type* **display** and return the unformatted data for any other value in *type*.

```
"render" : function( data , type , row ) {    
    if ( type === "display" )
    {
       // format data here
       return data; // This is formatted data
    }    
    return data; // This is unformatted data    
}
```

Comment: Damn I was almost close, Thanks for the help mate, It worked :)

Comment: Awesome solution! Save to me lots of refactoring. Thanks!

Comment: This is something that should be added to the manual because the sorting approach of the software is rather opaque.

Comment: OMG this just save my day